# Active record CONCAT select fields in a relationship not working

Tags: activerecord, yii2

I have the following dataprovider. Parentgroups is related to parentchildren via one-many relationship.

I am trying the concat the ChildFirstName and ChildLastName but it is not displaying. Only ID and ParentID is displaying.

```
$query = Parentgroups::find();

            $query->with(
                [ 
                    'parents' => function( $query){
                        $query->select([ 'Name', 'ID' ]);
                    },
                    'parentchildren' => function ( $query ){
                        $query->select([ new \yii\db\Expression("CONCAT('ChildFirstName', 'ChildLastName') as childName"), 'ID', 'ParentID' ]);
                    }
                ]
            );

            $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
                'query' => $query,
                'pagination' => false,
            ]);
```

I referred to this link: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/8276

But it didn't worked for me. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: did you added `childName` property into your child model ?

Comment: Oops I missed it. After adding, it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `childName` property into your child model, so it will be populated automatically by yii. [Yii2 docs about selecting extra fields](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#selecting-extra-fields)